# Loop through different ranges with variable bounds

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to copy different columns up to the last row used and just loop through every range I'm trying to access. For this I declared an array that stores the first half of the range (fixed) and add the last row with *& LastRow* within the Range() but I always get an error **Run-time error 9 Subscript out of range** when looping through these ranges (the first row of the loop is marked). I just don't get why this isn't working (storing the *& LastRow* in the array doesn't work either). I need this LastRow to be variable since it's going to change in the later section of the macro.

```
Sub ImportRows()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CopiedColumns As Variant
Dim InsertColumns As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
CopiedColumns = Array("A2:A", "C2:C", "F2:F", "J2:J", "L2:L")

'Copy Paste
'###########################################

InsertColumns = Array("A2:A", "B2:B", "C2:C", "D2:D", "E2:E")
With wbk.Worksheets("RawData")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 1 To 5
    wbk.Worksheets("RawData").Range(CopiedColumns(i) & LastRow).Copy
    wbk.Worksheets("Comparrisson").Range(InsertColumns(i) & LastRow).Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks for literally any help!

Comment: Both your arrays are 1D type. They are zero based. You should iterate between 0 and 4. Please, try running the code line by line (using F8). Does your code raise that error at the first iteration? Isn't it use the second range of the array? Do all columns have the same number of rows?

Comment: At what line the mentioned error is raised? Correcting the iteration, your code should work as it is. Of course, if the two mentioned sheets exist...

Comment: It really seems to just have been the looping from 1 to 5...  The first iterations worked and when changing it to 0 to 4, it worked, thanks a lot! Sometimes the most obvious things are the toughest to spot

Comment: In the meantime I posted a piece of code avoiding to use clipboard. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments, your code should work if the iteration is adapted to 1D arrays type. Please, test the next code, using only arrays and not involving the clipboard, slowing Excel and consuming more resources:

```
Sub ImportColumns()
 Dim wbk As Workbook, LastRow As Long, CopiedColumns, InsertColumns As Variant
 Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, i As Long, arrC

 Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
 CopiedColumns = Array("A2:A", "C2:C") ', "F2:F", "J2:J", "L2:L")

 Set sh = wbk.Worksheets("RawData")
 Set sh1 =  wbk.Worksheets("Comparrisson")
 'Copy columns
 '###########################################

 InsertColumns = Array("A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2")
 LastRow = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

 For i = 0 To 1
    arrC = sh.Range(CopiedColumns(i) & LastRow)
    sh1.Range(InsertColumns(i)).Resize(UBound(arrC), 1).value = arrC
 Next i
End Sub
```

And a more compact solution, not involving any iteration:

```
Sub ImportColumnsArr()
 Dim wbk As Workbook, LastRow As Long, arr, arrC
 Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet

 Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
 
 Set sh = wbk.Worksheets("RawData")
 Set sh1 = wbk.Worksheets("Comparrisson")
 LastRow = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

 arr = sh.Range("A2:L" & LastRow).value
 
 arrC = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), Array(1, 3, 5, 10, 12))
 'Copy columns:
 sh1.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrC), UBound(arrC, 2)).value = arrC
End Sub
```

Comment: @jnskls: I new that they work... I only wanted to make you explore some deeper codding ways...